# Does TMS only check the version number of the localized component to decide if Component is eligible for Translation?

Tags: translation-manager, 2013-sp1-hr1

As mentioned in the SDL Doc, in the section of **“Resolving of push translations”:**

*“Localized items are always valid inclusions, except when the item has not been translated (an item is considered to have been translated when it has version 2.0 or higher)”*

But I can have the version greater than 2 even if I keep updating the same component and check-in multiple times which may result to version 4 or 5, so does that mean TMS won’t resolve this component during translation and exclude it?

I think TMS should or must already be checking the version history too to find if component is checked-in by MTSUser then only it should conclude that the component is translated?

Is there any other article or blog someone refer to which focuses more on TMS internal algorithms/logics?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-18A6C654-D0EE-433F-8C58-CE6EF860A748) is describing how "Push" translations are resolved. That is, where you have chosen source content in a high publication to be translated in one or more lower publications lower in the BluePrint. In this case, Translation Manager will use any components which have been localised in any intermediate publications as a source. This is because, for example, there may be some regional localisations (mph vs. kph or left hand drive vs. right hand drive in an automotive use case) that need to be included in the requested translations. Without including them, any existing localisation would be skipped and the returned content would be translated directly from the top level.

The reason that Translation Manager skips localised items with only one version is because a localised item immediately becomes version 1 before modification, i.e. it has been localised but no changes have been made. If a localised item has been modified (has a version number of 2 or higher) it **is** used as a source, this is what is meant by:

> "Localized items are always valid inclusions, except when the item has
>   not been translated (an item is considered to have been translated
>   when it has version 2.0 or higher)"

Perhaps the documentation could be worded a little clearer - something like:

*"Localized items are always valid inclusions, except when the item has not been translated (an item is considered to have not been translated when it only has a version 1.0)"*

TM does not check for changes made by the MTSUser - That may not be the user that TM is running as and/or TMS may not be the only process changing data as that user. TM does maintain some data (I think it's stored as AppData) to keep track of what items were translated as part of which TM jobs.

Comment: Thanks @David for detailed explanation which is clear to me now. But I see a problem in this case. Let's assume we have 020 EN Master Publication which have all English Content and being inherited by 030 FR-FR which in turn inherited by 040 BE-FR, so theoretically during Push if I initiate the translation of a component from 020 EN to 040 BE-FR, but the same component is localized with version 7.0 in 030 FR, the TMS will include the localized copy present in 030 FR rather than sending from 020 EN even though if I want the translation from English to Belgium French & not from FR to BE-FR?

Comment: Well that depends - Have you configured your 030 FR-FR publication to be a _source for translation_? I suspect you have not, in which case the 020 EN Master Publication content will still be used. Remember that the inclusion of localised items only applies if their context publications are configured as sources for translation.